# Appending one txt file content to another exiting txt file

Tags: php, file

I am trying to append the `names.txt` file content to the another file called as `surname.txt` at the end of the file , without losing previous information of `surname.txt` .

What is possible way to achieve this operation ?  To execute this operation , i am using php

Following solution working perfect ! but data is not inserting to new line.

Answer (score 4):

Like below, using `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/surname.txt', file_get_contents('/path/to/names.txt'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: How i can check , if file is exists or not ?

Comment: File_exists working perfect dude , Now issue is of new line. its not using new line :( How i can insert this into new line.

Comment: @user2345691 Add new line "\n" ? No effort from you at all ?

Comment: I've used "\n" file_put_contents($file['surname.txt'], file_get_contents($file['name.txt']), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX | PHP_EOL) Both are file name , how i can use "\n".. However I've tried to use but fetched errors.

Comment: use file_put_contents('/path/to/surname.txt', PHP_EOL . file_get_contents('/path/to/names.txt'), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: This is not very memory efficient if /path/to/names.txt is large, as file_get_contents will read the entire file in before sending to file_put_contents.